# Android For Loop Not stopping

Tags: android, loops, for-loop, invalidation

I'm playing around with 2 d graphics on android.  I'm using random generator for x and y using a for loop.  weird thing is that the loop never stops:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            invalidate();
            int randomX = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
            int randomY = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
            canvas.drawPoint(randomX, randomY, paint);
            float radius = 20;
            canvas.drawCircle(randomX, randomY, radius, paint);
        }
```

i look at the logcat it shows i = 0,1,2,3,4.  am i going blind??? i =

Comment: What value is shown after 4 has been printed?

Comment: Does the logcat show 0 - 4 multiple times, or just once? Or does the logcat show i going above 4?

Is there an outer loop or something else triggering your Activity?

Sorry, I'm not sure if there's enough information to really help here. Your for-loop looks fine in isolation (to me anyway).

Comment: how do you mean it does not stop? if your logcat just shows i=0,1,2,3,4 and nothing more then it has stopped.

Comment: `System.out.println` shouldn't print anything in logcat. Use `Log.i` or `System.err.println`

Comment: the loop reaches 4 and then repeats. try it out.  the loop just resets once it reaches 4.

Comment: i just realized that its the invalidate() that's screwing the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `for` loop is inside the `onDraw()` method of a view, calling `invalidate()` will force the view to redraw itself, calling `onDraw()` again, thus the infinite loop.